# Javascript learning 2nd iteration of if for loop - School work

Tags: javascript, function, iteration

Updated: Halfway Solved:

I was able to solve the main function of getting the start variables to reach the end nodes. I am lost again on how to track the path i took and and it to console log or a return. I updated the code.

I am at the tail end of finishing this project maybe. I need to compare my queue and visited nodes some how so i dont revisit the same nodes over and over again. Also the end node is being reached but never registers.

I am having a hard time solving a game board problem. I am able to iterate through my helper function once and it stops. I am confused on why my while loop will not grab the current answers, add to the current solutions and make a X on the board. I have tried a lot of different answers. I need the for Loop to loop more than once and the board to update with a X where it has been. I also need the queue and visited arrays to update

This is supposed to be a shortest first path function that reaches the end nodes via the findpath function. I loop in all possible directions of a knights piece on a chess board until the end position is reached or I run out of spaces or items in queue

```
let board = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
]

queue = []
visited = []

let counter = 0

let xPossibleMoves = [2, 1,-1,-2, -2, -1, 1, 2]
let yPossibleMoves = [1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2,-2,-1]


function findPath(currentX, currentY, endX, endY){

    //console.log(currentX, currentY)

    
    //console.log(queue)
    
    //console.log(visited)

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    let vectorX = currentX + xPossibleMoves[i]
    let vectorY = currentY + yPossibleMoves[i]

    if(board[vectorX] == undefined || board[vectorY] == undefined)
    continue

    if(board[vectorX][vectorY] == "X")        
    continue

    

    //console.log("next hop X: " + vectorX + " Y: " + vectorY)

    queue.push(vectorX, vectorY)
    visited.push(vectorX, vectorY)
    
    board[vectorX][vectorY] = "X"
    }   
    //console.log(board)
    
}

function knightsMove(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
    //console.log(board[endX][endY])
    
      let currentX = queue.push(startX);
      let currentY = queue.push(startY);
     
      //board[endX][endY] = "END";
      //board[startX][startY] = "START";

      do{     

        findPath(currentX, currentY, endX, endY)

        
        if([currentX, currentY] === [endX, endY])
        console.log("found")
        

        currentX = queue.shift()
        currentY = queue.shift()

        //console.log(visited)
        

        //console.log(board[currentX][currentY]) //Gives me the X's
        if(board[endX][endY] == "X")
            return newPath(startX, startY, endX, endY) + ' Done'//`done start: ${startX}, ${startY} to ${endX}, ${endY}`
        
      } while(queue.length > 0) 
      
}

    console.log(knightsMove(0,0,5,4))

    //let xPossibleMoves = [2, 1,-1,-2, -2, -1, 1, 2]
    //let yPossibleMoves = [1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2,-2,-1]

    function newPath(startX, startY, endX, endY){
    return `start: ${startX}, ${startY} to ${endX}, ${endY}`
        
    }
```

I tried adding do while loop, while loop, making a prototype of original instance, tons of different variations, modifiying any errors that would prevent the loop, addin a function to update everything and push the while loop and etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *At a glance*... The `while` loop at the end of the `findPath` function is superfluous.  The loop body *returns* from the function, which would immediately end the loop.  Is that the problem you're describing?  What do you expect that function to return?

Comment: You should really format your code. There is a tool called "Prettier" that can format your code: [link to playground](https://prettier.io/playground/). If you paste you code over there and format, you can get a better understanding of your code. I noticed that your `return` statement is inside your `while` condition. I would recommend that you _always_ use braces for loops and conditionals. It will lead you to less bugs overall.

Comment: I reformatted the code with prettier so it looks better.  I have added brackets to the while loop as well. It is a path finding problem from start to end.

@David I am looking at that right now and probably is.

Comment: I was able to solve the main function of getting the start variables to reach the end nodes. I am lost again on how to track the path i took and and it to console log or a return. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

## Cleaned Up A Bit

Well...I don't want to do your entire homework assignment, but I have a few, old snippets I keep around in Chrome. This should at least help clean up your output and make debugging easier. I know the feeling too -- you end up with more lines of `console.log(...)` than you do lines of actual code.

```js
console.clear();
// This is just a variable to help differentiate the console output lines.
let dumpInfoCount = 0;

// Some console styles to make reading the output a little easier...
cs = {
  h1: "font-size:150%;",
  h2: "font-size:130%;",
  i: "font-style: italic;",
  b: "font-weight:bold;",
  attn: "color: #fff;background-color:#990000;",
  warn: "color: #ffcc00;",
  good: "color: #009900;",
  info: "color: #00ccff;",
  gray: "color: #ccc;",
  reset: "color: inherit;font-size:100%;",
};

let board = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
queue = [];
visited = [];
let counter = 0;
let xPossibleMoves = [2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2];
let yPossibleMoves = [1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1];

/**
 * Clean up code by removing all the `console.log(...)`
 * lines. Also makes it easier to turn it all off later.
 */
function dumpInfo(cx, cy, extraMessage) {
  console.groupCollapsed(
    "%cInfo Number:%c %d %c%s",
    cs.warn,
    cs.reset,
    dumpInfoCount,
    cs.info,
    extraMessage ? extraMessage : ""
  );
  console.log(
    "%cPassed In %cX%c,%cY:%c %d , %d",
    cs.info,
    cs.good,
    cs.reset,
    cs.good,
    cs.reset,
    cx,
    cy
  );
  console.log("%cBoard:%c %o", cs.info, cs.reset, board);
  console.log("%cQueue:%c %o", cs.info, cs.reset, queue);
  console.log("%cVisited:%c %o", cs.info, cs.reset, visited);
  console.groupEnd();
  dumpInfoCount += 1;
}

function findPath(currentX, currentY, endX, endY) {
  dumpInfo(currentX, currentY);

  // Not sure why the need to clone into `visited` here. Nothing happens with it.
  // queue.forEach(function (item) {
  // visited.push(item);
  // });
  // dumpInfo(currentX, currentY);

  console.groupCollapsed("%cInner Loop Here", cs.attn);

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let vectorX = currentX + xPossibleMoves[i];
    let vectorY = currentY + yPossibleMoves[i];

    // Just be mindful that we're passing a differnt X/Y pair, here...
      dumpInfo(vectorX, vectorY, "Next Move: "+vectorX+", " + vectorY);

    if (board[vectorX] == undefined || board[vectorY] == undefined) continue;

    if (board[vectorX][vectorY] == "X") continue;

    if (board[vectorX][vectorY] == "END") return "DONE";

    queue.push(vectorX, vectorY);
    board[vectorX][vectorY] = "X";
  }
  console.groupEnd();
  //Stuff out of my for loop happens Once
  tail = 2;
  queue = queue.slice(tail);

  dumpInfo(currentX, currentY, "BEFORE Queue to Visited");

  /**
   * Why not just remove an item from your queue...? Try [Array.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
   * It removes the last item and returns it, like this:
   *
   * let nextItem = queue.pop();
   */
  queue.forEach(function (item) {
    visited.push(item);
  });
  dumpInfo(currentX, currentY, "AFTER Queue to Visited");

  // console.error("What are you doing with this `item` anyway? %o");
  queue.forEach((item) => {
    findPath(currentX, currentY, endX, endY);
  });
  //   while (queue.length > 0 && board[[endX][endY]] == null)
  //     return findPath(currentX, currentY, endX, endY);

  /**
   * Need to decide what the final return value is. It's not
   * clear how you're defining "success", here.
   */
  return { currentX, currentY, endX, endY };
}

function knightsMove(startX, startY, endX, endY) {
  if (board[endX][endY] == null) {
    // let currentX = startX;
    // let currentY = startY;

    queue.push(startX);
    queue.push(startY);
    board[endX][endY] = "END";
    board[startX][startY] = "START";

    dumpInfo(startX, startY);

    return findPath(startX, startY, endX, endY);
  }
}

knightsMove(0, 0, 3, 3);
```

##### Sample Screen Shot

[image: Example of what some of the output could look like in Chrome Developer Tools Console]

#### Bonus Info

I used to use a cool, little Chrome extension called **jsShell**, but the guy stopped supporting it. Nowadays I use something called [**Snippets**](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/snippets/fakjeijchchmicjllnabpdkclfkpbiag). I know it doesn't have any automation to it (like `run this script if the URL matches this regex` kind of thing), but it *does* sync everything with my GitHub account. So that's nice -- you could pretty much access it from a browser at school, home, work, VM, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, I didnt even know that console log could do that. That is amazing!!! Thanks for the assist. This is the hardest problem solving I have done yet.

Comment: Ya, there's some pretty useful stuff in the documentation. Checkout the [**Console API**](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api#log). There's other stuff that might be useful to your debugging efforts as well. For example, you could dump an Object into a table, if it's easier to read, by using [`console.table(...)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api#table).Of course, IMHO, the key in victory for large tables is using it with [`console.groupCollapsed(label)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api#groupcollapsed) and `console.groupEnd()`.